# Magento Multi-store parked domain - weird domain url jump in admin panel and front end

Tags: php, magento

I am running Magento Multi-store (store views) with parked domain for different countries (e.g. .com.au, .co.nz)

When I am navigating around in the admin panel of .com.au (which is the main store view), sometimes the domain will get changed to .co.nz which disabled me to perform certain actions like changing order status.

Also while customers are navigating in .com.au site, sometimes it bring them to .co.nz shopping cart after clicking "add to cart".

Does anyone have any solution or idea what might have went wrong? Please help.